# R: stat_sf requires the following missing aesthetics: geometry

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following data:

```
library(leaflet)
library(leafgl)
library(colourvalues)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(gridExtra)

nc <- st_read(system.file("gpkg/nc.gpkg", package="sf"), quiet = TRUE) %>% 
    st_transform(st_crs(4326)) %>% 
    st_cast('POLYGON')


set.seed(123) 

nc$obesity_rate1 <- sample(0:100, nrow(nc), replace = TRUE)
pal1 <- colorNumeric(palette = "YlOrRd", domain = nc$obesity_rate1)

nc$obesity_rate2 <- sample(0:100, nrow(nc), replace = TRUE)
pal2 <- colorNumeric(palette = "YlOrRd", domain = nc$obesity_rate2)

nc$obesity_rate3 <- sample(0:100, nrow(nc), replace = TRUE)
pal3 <- colorNumeric(palette = "YlOrRd", domain = nc$obesity_rate3)
```

**I am trying to make 3 maps for this data and put them together on the same plot.**

I know 2 different ways to do this:

**Method 1:**

```
g1 = ggplot() +
geom_sf(data = nc,
aes(fill = cut_number(obesity_rate1, 5)),
alpha = 0.8,
colour = 'white',
size = 0.3) +
scale_fill_brewer(palette = "PuBu",
name = "Legend (%)") +
labs(x = NULL, y = NULL,
title = "Title1",
subtitle = "",
caption = "") +
theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
line = element_blank(),
axis.text = element_blank(),
axis.title = element_blank()) +
coord_sf(datum = NA)


g2 = ggplot() +
geom_sf(data = nc,
aes(fill = cut_number(obesity_rate2, 5)),
alpha = 0.8,
colour = 'white',
size = 0.3) +
scale_fill_brewer(palette = "PuBu",
name = "Legend (%)") +
labs(x = NULL, y = NULL,
title = "Title2",
subtitle = "",
caption = "") +
theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
line = element_blank(),
axis.text = element_blank(),
axis.title = element_blank()) +
coord_sf(datum = NA)


g3 = ggplot() +
geom_sf(data = nc,
aes(fill = cut_number(obesity_rate3, 5)),
alpha = 0.8,
colour = 'white',
size = 0.3) +
scale_fill_brewer(palette = "PuBu",
name = "Legend (%)") +
labs(x = NULL, y = NULL,
title = "Title3",
subtitle = "",
caption = "") +
theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
line = element_blank(),
axis.text = element_blank(),
axis.title = element_blank()) +
coord_sf(datum = NA)


grid.arrange(g1, g2, g3, ncol = 3)
```

**Method 2:**

library(tidyr)

```
nc_long <- nc %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = c(obesity_rate1,  obesity_rate2, obesity_rate3),
                 names_to = "variable",
                 values_to = "value")

ggplot(nc_long) +
    geom_sf(aes(fill = value)) +
    facet_wrap(variable ~ .) +
    scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red") +
    theme_void() +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

**My Question:** Although this code runs for this simulated dataset used in this example - in my actual problem, when I run the code, I get the following error (for both Methods):

```
stat_sf requires the following missing aesthetics: geometry
```

**The interesting thing is that I can make each map individually without any problems, and then manually copy/paste each map - but I can't seem to put them all on the same page using either of these methods.**

I have tried to debug this error but cant seem to figure it out.

Can anyone please suggest what to do? Is there another method I can consider trying?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid that your reprex does not target the issue you are having. That error occurs when `ggplot()` or `geom_sf()` `data` parameter is an object without geometry, i.e. regular data.frame / tibble is used instead of sf object. Perhaps check object types right before ggplot calls.